# Wordpress Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using the following code 
`

```
$(function(){
            $('#main_cat').change(function(){
                    var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();

                    // call ajax
                     $("#sub_cat").empty();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                            type:'POST',
                            data:'my_special_ajax_call&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

                             success:function(results)
                                 {
                                  alert(results);
                $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#sub_cat").append(results);
                                        }
                                   });
                          }
                                    );
});
```

`And i had already defined a function in function.php`my_special_ajax_call()` but i am not getting the correct response. Its sending me  -1 every time can anyone help me out???

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $wpdb;
$siteurl=get_option('siteurl'); ?>
$(function(){
        $('#main_cat').change(function(){
                var $mainCat=$('#main_cat').val();

                // call ajax
                 $("#sub_cat").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo $siteurl; ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'my_special_ajax_call&main_catid=' + $mainCat,

                         success:function(results)
                             {
                              alert(results);
            $("#sub_cat").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#sub_cat").append(results);
                                    }
                               });
                      }
                                );
});
Try this code.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah that is a good way to avoid path issue. But here i am facing different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I got the error yesterday only but couldn't post it was simple typing error i missed out "action" from `data:'action=my_special_ajax_call&main_catid='_$mainCat,`

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

Consider following the practices showed in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and using the `admin_url()` function to get the actual url of *admin-ajax.php*